# Unit Testing GetManifestResourceStream

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Quick question about unit testing.

My application has a few embeded Xml files, they are often added and sometimes removed. I have a method that I want to unit test that contains the line

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(xmlFile)
```

where `xmlFile` is a parameter

Because of this the test will become dependent on a particular xml file being there, and there is a chance it could be removed at a later date, which is fine, but would break my test when really it shouldn't.

Does anybody know anyway around this dependency other than removing this line of code and passing it into the method instead (That will only mean I have to test it else where).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use GetManifestResourceNames().  Only run the test on the names you discover this way.

Comment: Thank you. You also saved me :)